# WPF Vertical menu - showing first sub menu on left

Tags: wpf, menu

I am currently trying to make the WPF menu render vertically. I used the following code :

```
<Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Menu.ItemsPanel>
```

which is ok but I would like the submenus to show on left of each root menuitem. 
any pointers on how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the styling and templating method to create your new MenuItem template. For the detail of styling and templating see this MSDN article on [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)

Creating or modifying a template for a MenuItem can be done easily in Expression Blend, See 
this MSDN article [Create or modify a template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908%28v=expression.30%29.aspx)

The default setting for the place of the sub-MenuItem is on the right of the root MenuItem except for the TopLevelHeader menuitem whose sub-MenuItems are a dropdown. If you want to set the TopLevelHeader MenuItem's also to be on the right, you just need to create a new template of the default MenuItem and modify the setting for the TopLevelHeader MenuItem. In blend, you just need to revise the "ResourceId" to be "SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey" in the section of the XAML code for the template.

```
    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
    </Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tweak template of the **MenutItem** control. If you don't have any examples of this control's template, you could create one using blend's feature "edit template -> edit a copy...".
There, you have to find a **Popup** control and change its **Placement property** to whatever you want. This popup is where the subitems are hosted.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
</Menu>
```

I hope that this is may help